# No puedo enviar solicitud a una API desde mi PC

Tags: laravel, api, localhost, certificado-ssl

Que tal? quizás alguien pueda ayudarme con esta duda. El día de ayer estaba conectando una app web a un REST API. Hice las pruebas primero con curl desde un Ubuntu WSL y posteriormente desde Postman y las peticiones funcionaron correctamente, sin embargo al hacerlo desde la app no me devuelve ninguna información. Esto me pareció extraño así que lo hice desde otra computadora y oh sorpresa, desde ahí si se envían las peticiones desde la app web. Estoy trabajando con Laravel y en los logs me devuelve únicamente el siguiente error:

```
[2022-05-11 09:20:25] local.ALERT:
```

Al extraer el error de la petición me devuelve:

```
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Desactivé el antivirus pensando que quizás tenía algo que ver pero tampoco funcionó. Si alguien puede darme una idea de lo que está pasando, lo agradecería mucho. Con todo esto debo solucionarlo si o si, entonces si encuentro una respuesta la estaré publicando aquí mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionaba, venía a traer respuestas si no recibía ninguna. Inicialmente seguí las sugerencias de esta web de aquí -> [https://komodor.com/learn/how-to-fix-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-git-error/#:~:text=When%20ssl%20certificate%20problem%20unable,to%20the%20trusted%20certificate%20store.&text=Open%20the%20file%20ca%2Dbundle,the%20end%20of%20the%20file](https://komodor.com/learn/how-to-fix-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-git-error/#:%7E:text=When%20ssl%20certificate%20problem%20unable,to%20the%20trusted%20certificate%20store.&text=Open%20the%20file%20ca%2Dbundle,the%20end%20of%20the%20file).

Pero nada de eso me funcionó, así que finalmente entré directamente en mi código en la consulta de PHP que llama a la API y agregué los siguientes parámetros en mi consulta:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2, //en producción siempre 2 por seguridad
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0, //en 0 para que se salte la verificación del peer del certificado
```

Esta última información la saqué de la siguiente web -> https://aboutssl.org/fix-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/ y de la documentación de PHP. Con mi jefe queremos ver si esto no nos causa ninguna brecha de seguridad pero mientras no se cargue a producción, se lo trabajará así para poder realizar la tarea. Si alguien puede explicarme que es lo que está pasando, se lo agradecería mucho pero por lo pronto esa es la solución. :)

Comment: CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER no debería estar apagado. Si la validación falla, es porque no le es posible al servidor ir y validar si el root CA del certificado del servicio es válido. Apagarlo es exponerse a ataques Man In The Middle. Posiblemente [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18972719/236345) de SO sirva.